# Good Server Primer

Tags: web-server

A friend of mine asked me for a "servers 101" type resource where he could quickly learn the important, though basic, things a beginner trying to wrap their head around servers would need to know.

Topics like Server OS's, Shared vs Virtual vs Private, etc would all be useful.

I know enough to get by doing what I need to do with the knowledge, but I can't explain it to him well.

Just trying to see if anyone has possibly come across an article covering this.

Answer (score 1):

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server) has good stuff. So does [google](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=server%20basics)

Answer (score 0):

Came across this: [part one](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/SERVER-PRIMER,1563.html) of a [slightly more difficult than I was looking for, but] good primer. And [part two](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/SERVER-PRIMER,1576.html).